# Google tells do not change dynamic URLs, and offers this instead, how?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

> If you want to serve a static equivalent of your site, you might want to consider transforming the underlying content by serving a replacement which is truly static. One example would be to generate files for all the paths and make them accessible somewhere on your site.

What they mean exactly? And how to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more relevant on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question: **What do they mean exactly?**

*If you want to serve a static equivalent of your site* - static refers to html pages that are not dynamically created.

*you might want to consider transforming the underlying content by serving a replacement which is truly static.* Have 'hard copies' of your pages with the different alternatives

*One example would be to generate files for all the paths and make them accessible somewhere on your site.* Go through your site and create static html pages (or pdf's) of each one and store them in the file structure that is represented by the URL.

Example of the last:
http://site.tld/product/pear which today is a dynamic (created on the fly by the code and database) but is not really in an actual folder on the server called product. They are suggesting to create a copy of the dynamically created page and store it in an actual folder on the server called product with the name pear.

Your question **And how to do it?**

Will that work - sort of if you wanted to by adding a .html to the physical file (copy of the dynamic one) and save it but I suspect you will run into all sorts of difficulties that you will need to overcome with the redirect code in places like .htaccess. Another option may be change the domain part of the URL to include static ie http://static.site.tld/ for the static copies and the original URL as is for the dynamic version.

The other big challenge then becomes maintaining the two copies because the concept they talk about is for the content (what is shown in the browser) to remain static over time. Kind of breaks the whole concept of how we build dynamic web sites today e.g. online shops etc.

For example if it's a shop, I would use PHP to also create the physical file when a product is added and not include parts that are going to change, rather include a link to the dynamic info something like:

```
<?php
  $file = 'product/pear.html';
  // mysql code here to extract the info and format ready for writing
  $content = "<html><head><title>$title_from_db</title></head><body>$page_content_from_db</body></html>";
  // Write the contents to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know why some people here like to give negative votes to other members questions.